# Program shuts down silently

Tags: c++, multithreading, crash

There is a multithreaded program that operates simultaneously with a device via COM port based communication and remote (IP) video stream. The program also uses OpenCV library to process the data.

The trouble is that it shuts down without any signals (neither run-time, nor any other errors are caught; log file has no anything useful as well). The most top level application error event handler is set and still there are no any signs of the program crash. It just closes after awhile.

The biggest difficulty is that it works fine on all our PCs for days non-stop. But fails on customers PCs so that testing process is very slow. Customer is in a different country (Asian localization, whilst ours is European), but the program is built with Unicode support.

So far we have got some assumptions about localization issues and antivirus activity... but it gives nothing in result.

The program is written with MinGW 4.4.x C++ and wxWidgets 2.9.3

Any suggestions of the probable origin would be appreciate.

Comment: do all the shut downs occur after a similar time?

Comment: No, cases occur after a different time (10 min, 30 min, 1, 1.5h). But all the cases occur within first 1.5 hours. There might be some memory leaks, but I haven`t got any on our PC. But actually, I have not checked it for leaks connected with localization factors

Comment: You need a black box for your plane. You should create a version with massive logging so that you can locate the crash better, by looking at the last log entries it produced. After looking at them you can further refine them, to get even more detailed information on what was going on before the crash.

Comment: I hope you're testing it with the Asian localization.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is right. Before heavy logging and any other investigation, your first priority should be to _reproduce_ the crash. You _want_ to see your software crashing. Ask the customer for the OS version and other relevant data and reproduce their environment exactly. At a prior company in extreme cases we convinced the customer to send us their computer for some days to investigate with it, but first you should try to mimic their environment as closely as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

The problem was inside OpenCV build 2.3.1, that we use. The function cv::imdecode(...) uses stdio.h`s tempnam() function to generate temporary file during decoding. Under x86 Windows systems this function fails after 32767 new names for temporary file. Under x64 Windows systems it returns some nonsense string, but it still works.

So the solution I came with was to change the way of receiving-decoding images from our device.

Thanks everybody for comments.